# How to decrease amount of data returned by navigator.geolocation.watchPosition

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, geolocation

In ASP.NET MVC4 HTML5 application `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` is used to store car position data in server using script below in Android and Apple tablets.

This adds new record to Postgres 9.1 database after every second if car is moving.
This produces too much data and probably unnessecarily uses tablet accumulator power to get gps data.

How to reduce number of records stored in database?
Is is probably sufficient for my precision to send new position data only once per minute. How to decrease watchPosition transfer rate, is there some option for this ?

Or should MVC controller implement some method do create number of records saved in database ?

client:

```
        watchId=navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
            function success(position) {
                $.post( 'api/Soit?'+$.param({
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
                    }));
            },
            function errorCallback(err) {
            }, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            });
```

server:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public dynamic Soit([FromUri]int dokumnr, [FromUri]float latitude, [FromUri]float longitude)
        {
            Db.ExecCommand(@"insert into doksyndm (aeg, latitude, longitude)
values (current_timestamp, {0},{1})", latitude, longitude);
            return new
            {
                Message = "OK"
            };
        }
```

Postgres 9.1, ASP .NET MVC4, ASP.NET Web API, jQuery, Bootstrap 3, jQuery UI are used.

Comment: You'll have to manually check when you sent the last location and adjust the rate.

Comment: Checking in javascript still allows watchPositon to read position too rapidly. This decreases accumulator life. How to decreace the rate which watchPosition calls success method ? How ot force watchPosition to read position only once per minute ?

Comment: Not possible. It will provide the location whenever it wants, which usually is once per second if changes have happened.

Comment: So creating global javascript variable `lastReadingTime` and comparing it with current time in `success` event handler is the only solution ? Or should `readingCount` variable used to send only every 60th reading to server?